# Restrict expedited retrievals for S3 Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

Is there any way to restrict **expedited** retrievals for S3 Glacier? Or allow restore-priority=**bulk** only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) documentation page only shows the following `Condition Keys` on `RestoreObject`:

- s3:DataAccessPointAccount
- s3:DataAccessPointArn
- s3:AccessPointNetworkOrigin
- s3:authType
- s3:ResourceAccount
- s3:signatureAge
- s3:signatureversion
- s3:TlsVersion
- s3:x-amz-content-sha256

Therefore, it doesn't seem possible to limit permissions based on a restoration priority.